# CONCAT a subquery result and fixed strings

Tags: mysql, subquery, concatenation

I want to create a virtual column.
It is made of a column, a subquery and fixed string.

The current code uses the subquery as a string and it's not executed.

```
SELECT X.vname, X.id, CONCAT(X.vname, '..' ,SELECT T.id FROM T WHERE T.x_id=X.id LIMIT 1, '..', 'some_text') FROM xtable AS X
```

Results as: `vname_value..SELECT T.id FROM T WHERE T.x_id=X.id LIMIT 1..some_text`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this, surround the sub-query with bracket

```
SELECT X.vname, X.id, CONCAT(X.vname, '..' ,(SELECT T.id FROM T WHERE T.x_id=X.id LIMIT 1), '..', 'some_text') FROM xtable
```

Comment: Don't forget `AS X` at the end of the statement.